# Importing test reports from external system to Azure DevOps?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, gitlab-ci

I know that in Azure DevOps I can create test cases for my features and I can collect those test cases in a test suite to keep track of test results for a particular release or iteration of my software.

I also know that on a code level I can integrate a test framework to run unit or integration tests. Depending on the technology stack and language that I use the frameworks differ (i.e., Mocha, Junit, NUnit, PyTest, etc.), but usually they produce a common format for test results such as an XML Test Report using the [JUnit Schema](https://github.com/windyroad/JUnit-Schema).

Now, I run my unit tests in different tools (i.e., Gitlab CI/CD or Jenkins) and I would like to link the test results from those unit and integration tests to test cases that I am collecting in test suites on Azure DevOps.

If I understand this correctly, then the link to bring this together is the test case ID on Azure DevOps which I somehow need to correlate with the individual unit tests in my test framework.

Once my test suite has run in the external tool, how can I publish the test report (i.e., a JUnit XML) to Azure DevOps to correlate the report with my test suite?

Is there a specific Azure DevOps API that I can use (i.e., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/) to publish a JUnit test report?